# Regression model with keras

Tags: python, pandas, keras

I'm trying to build my first regression model with Keras and what I'm seeying makes no sence to me. My code:

```
import pandas as pd

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

def build_model(X, y):
    display(X.shape)

    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu', input_shape=(X.shape[1],)))
    model.add(Dense(1))

    model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit(X, y, epochs=20)

    _, accuracy = model.evaluate(X, y)
    print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy*100))

    return model

X=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5], 'b':[2,3,4,5,6]})
y=pd.Series([3,4,5,6,7])

model = build_model(X, y)

df = pd.DataFrame({'y': y, 'predict_y': [x for [x] in model.predict(X)]})

print(df)
print(df.corr())
```

Prints something like:

```
(5, 2)
Epoch 1/20
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 13ms/step - loss: 20.8061 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/20
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 351us/step - loss: 20.6125 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
...
Epoch 19/20
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 314us/step - loss: 17.5301 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 20/20
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 216us/step - loss: 17.3576 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step
Accuracy: 0.00
   y  predict_y
0  3   0.525354
1  4   0.775924
2  5   1.003626
3  6   1.231329
4  7   1.459031
                  y  predict_y
y          1.000000   0.999806
predict_y  0.999806   1.000000
```

On the correlation matrix all seem good, almost 100% correlation. When I dump the y and the prediction I see that the values are somehow scaled.

Can someone make sence of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `accuracy` as your metric, even though your loss function is set to `mean_squared_error`.

Running again but then with `metrics=['mse']` should give you better results:

```
   y  predict_y
0  3   1.753360
1  4   2.771525
2  5   3.788639
3  6   4.803446
4  7   5.818252
             y  predict_y
y          1.0        1.0
predict_y  1.0        1.0
```